# How to make calculations in if statement with decimals in bash script

Tags: bash, decimal

```
 #SET INITIAL SPEED
initialspeed() {

wpm=$2

#CHECKS IF SPEED WAS GIVEN
if [ -z "$wpm" ]
then
let wpm=0.6
sleep $wpm

#CHECK IF SPEED IS VALID
elif [ $wpm > 0.6 ]
then
echo Error speed is less than 100 wpm
exit 3
elif [ $wpm < 0.06 ]
then
echo Error speed is more than 1000 wpm
exit 3
else
sleep $wpm
fi
}
```

I am trying to set a speed for my sleep timer but I think I am running into problems because of the decimals in the `let` and `if statements`. How do I use decimals in a bash script? Examples would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Not possible in native bash, use ``bc`` instead

Comment: i understand that but can you please give an example on how to us bc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` is limited to integer arithmetic.

If you have GNU tools (such as Linux), floating point comparisons can be done with `bc` as follows:

```
if echo "$wpm > 0.6" | bc -l | grep -q 1
then
    echo speed is greater than 0.6
else
    echo speed is less than or equal to 0.6
fi
```

With a non-GNU `bc`, the same can be done with a slightly longer statement:

```
if echo "if ($wpm > 0.6) print 1 else print 0 " | bc -l | grep -q 1
then
    echo speed is greater than 0.6
else
    echo speed is less than or equal to 0.6
fi
```